# limit the numbers of regsub commands to delete spaces, end of line or carriage return in list

Tags: regex, tcl

My list :

```
set myList "{ 
                {key value} {key1 value1}
                {
                    {key2 value2} {key3 value3}
                }
            }"
```

Desired output :

```
{{key value} {key1 value1} {{key2 value2} {key3 value3}}}
```

What I’ve tried so far:

```
set myList  [string trim $myList]
set newList [string map {\n "" \t " "} $myList]

regsub -all {^\{\s+\{} $newList "{{"  newList ; # start of list
regsub -all {\}\s+\}$} $newList "}}"  newList ; # end of list
regsub -all {\}\s+\{}  $newList "} {" newList ; # middle of list
regsub -all {\{\s+\{}  $newList "{{"  newList ; # middle of list again
regsub -all {\}\s+\}}  $newList "}}"  newList ; # middle of list again and again
```

It works , but I've used many `regsub` command.
Is it possible to limit them ? or a different approach, without `regsub`...

Comment: Maybe `regsub -all {(\{)\s+|\s+(\})|(\s)+} $myList {\1\2\3} myList;` will do? See https://ideone.com/6l9pZ4.

Comment: If you don't mind the lack of a space between `}` and `{` you could just match `\s*([{}])\s*` and replace with `\1` https://regex101.com/r/zj8Oa4/1

Comment: I'd probably start by normalizing all whitespace sequences to a single space (assuming there are no significant spaces in the leaves); that's one fast `regsub -all {\s+}`.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew, @CAustin, `regex` is definitely an enigma for me, your solution works for me, but the Donal's solution is 50x to 100x faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, doing it with `regsub` in 8.6 requires two, where one of them is decidedly ugly (using lookaheads):

```
regsub -all {(\{)\s+(?=[{}])|(\})\s+(?=\})} [regsub -all {(\})\s+(?=\{)} $myList {\1 }] {\1\2}
```

In 8.7, you can do it with one using the `-command` option (because you need the different substituent in some cases) but the RE itself will be uglier.

---

You can do it without `regsub`, but only if you know how deep you want to normalize (i.e., what the logical structure is); in your case, twice is enough:

```
lmap item $myList {
    lmap subitem $item {
        list {*}$subitem
    }
}
```

The command `list {*}$thing` is rather like `concat $thing` except that it is a proper list-native. `concat` *isn't* (and we have the test cases to prove it).

Comment: Getting the REs right is harder than it looks because you don't want to match the brace after the whitespace and can't use `\1` in a lookahead (RE engine limitation).

Comment: Awesome ! your solution without `regsub` is very fast. To compare with @WiktorStribiżew it is 100 times faster.I often try to avoid using regular expressions, I see why...(In this case)

Answer (score 0):

This removes leading/trailing whitespace from each line and also newlines

```
regsub -all -line {(^\s+)|(\s+$)|\n} $myList ""
# => {{key value} {key1 value1}{{key2 value2} {key3 value3}}}
```

It does remove the space between  sublists though.

```
regsub -all -line {(^\s+)|(\s+$)|\n} $myList "" flattened
regsub -all {\}\{} $flattened "} {"
# => {{key value} {key1 value1} {{key2 value2} {key3 value3}}}
```

Comment: thank you for this another solution...But Donal's answer without `regsub` it suits me better.